# File Explorer becomes unresponsive for a minute on startup (along with Taskbar) and always on refreshing (F5)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

| Edition | Windows 10 Pro |
| --- | --- |
| Version | 21H2 |
| OS build | 19044.1766 |
| Processor | Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz 1.10 GHz |
| Installed RAM | 4.00 GB (3.65 GB usable) |
| System type | 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor |

I don't exactly remember the cause of the problem, however IIRC I changed the virtual memory to custom size from automatic allocation or system managed size and it didn't restart properly and probably thereafter the problem started.

Problem & Its Symptoms:

- Upon startup the desktop comes with a non-responding taskbar and with no desktop icons loaded. After a minute or two, desktop icons becomes visible and taskbar starts working normal.
- Lunching windows explorer (file manager) looks working fine with all functions except manual refreshing with F5. When you try refreshing (F5), it becomes non-responsive for a minute and thereafter it starts working fine again until F5 is pressed again. The same effect is observed if refreshing is tried at Desktop icons.
- All other apps works fine but while clicking on Browse dialog to choose the file location, sometimes it may become unresponsive for a minute.
- The opened instance of windows explorer / file manager does all the jobs as expected but occasionally (say once in an hour) it becomes unresponsive and you have to wait for a minute.
- "Program Manager prevents windows from shutting down" while restarting the system

Trouble Shooting:

- `/sfc/scannow` completes with no issue found
- `dism`'s `CheckHealth` and `ScanHealth` finds no issue to resolve
- **Problem remains present with a clean boot** (though I couldn't disable sophos antivirus service)
- **Problem vanishes with booting into SafeMode** (Find [a comparison](https://cloud.disroot.org/s/KfGQa3YiLid4cBQ) of running services between SafeMode & CleanBoot)
- Automatic startup repair finds nothing to repair
- Windows Memory Diagnostic reports no problem.
- Windows update & automatic troubleshooter for the same doesn't find any issue

Tried following proposed solution but none of them helped:

- Cleaning File Explorer history, restoring settings to default and unchecking quick-access from "Folder Options"
- Resetting the virtual memory (page file) to automatic/system-managed
- Turning the fast boot on/off
- Disabling third party extensions using shellexview
- Uninstalling graphics driver and let the m re-installed upon startup
- System Restore

Might have tried random other proposed solutions also, add comment for clarification.

Have not tried following:

- Resetting windows which installs a fresh copy of Windows
- Repairing windows using Installation Disk.

Comment: Are you on a domain network?  If so, sign in as local admin or in safe-mode without networking and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: Are you working in a local network, domain or remote?

Comment: @Arctiic I sign in as a local admin (user who is member of Administrator Group). Tell me if any more details require, I'll share screenshot of particular settings/configuration.

Comment: @BlockchainOffice Local Admin Account

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm referring to a local Administrator account as in the type you would sign into with, e.g., `./administrator` for the user prompt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I, the author of the question has just upgraded to Windows 11 to get rid of the problem and hence can not verify answer any more.

Answer (score 1):

> "Problem vanishes with booting into SafeMode"

This means that some installed product is causing this problem.
You will need to locate the problem by disabling products in bunches,
until the problem vanishes, in order to locate the problematic product.

I would start with products that add entries to the context-menu of Explorer.

The products you can use :

- [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
  for disabling and re-enabling Startup programs.
- [NirSoft ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
  to disable and re-enable shell extensions of Explorer.

Comment: One other way to see what the explorer has loaded is to use the Process Explorer and look at the DLLs loaded.  I know that this isn't intuitive but you can also see the memory footprint of each DLL loaded in to get an idea of how sloppy the author was.

Comment: I have updated the question body with comparison between CleaBoot and SafeMode. Please have a look if it is useful for troubleshooting further.